# Векторное передвижение по игровому 2d миру, обход объектов по окружности

Tags: java, разработка-игр

Пишу небольшую игру, возникла проблема с обходом препятствий. Передвижение игрока осуществляется в место нажатия мышки. Беру начальные координаты(x,y) и конечные, вычисляю вектор передвижения, длину пути и единичный вектор. Все работает прекрасно, пока на пути не попадаются объекты. Все объекты в игре описаны окружностью, мы знаем центр и радиус. Проблема в том как вычислить новый путь для передвижения в указанную точку имея координаты центра окружности, радиус, единичный вектор и координаты столкновения с объектом? [image: Так примерно должно выглядеть]

Comment: Если персонаж дошел до точки С столкновения с окружностью, то его путь должен лежать по касательной к окружности. То есть вычисляем вектор CO и поворачиваем его на 90 градусом в обе стороны. Из двух полученных векторов берем тот, после движения по которому расстояние до точки B будет меньше. Повторить, пока не перестанем врезаться в окружность.

Comment: Более предпочтительный вариант реализовать pathfinding через A* (A-star) алгоритм и не заморачиваться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С кругом, в принципе, не нужен никакой алгоритм обхода путей. Достаточно сделать очень тупого, но очень напористого персонажа, который будет идти вперед не обращая внимание ни на что.

То есть, попадая в препятствие, он просто прекращает свое движение в сторону препятствия, но не прекращает движение в бок от него. То есть, он просто соскользнет с круг и продолжит путь в указанную точку.

Более умная модификация, это найти в точке столкновения касательную, либо перпендикуляр к АВ. После столкновения отойти по касательной(в сторону к объекту, либо где угол меньше к АВ) некоторое расстояние , чтобы оно точно было меньше радиуса круга, и потом попытаться проложить путь снова. И так пока не достигнет цели. С кругами проблем возникнуть не должно